# One-page scroll problems

Tags: javascript, css, scroll

I am using a free wordpress theme (I know, that is part of the problem :). It is a one-page scrolling theme with a sticky header. The problem is that the links do not hit the top of the sections - they scroll past. I did use CSS to increase the size of the header. If this throws it off that much how do I correct it in the coding?

site: http://whatsahead.com/closuremediatest/ (in the works)

The oddest part is it is not even consistent on where it lands on that section. What could be causing this?

CSS I edited:

```
`.navbar-collapse {
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) inset;
    overflow-x: visible;
    margin-left: 155px !important;
    padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  background: #000;
      margin-bottom: 30px !important;
    margin-left: 195px !important;
    margin-top: 50px;
    max-height: 65px;
}

#navigation .navbar-nav {
    float: left;
}

#navigation .navbar-nav > li > a {
    font-family: "aleolight";
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    background-color: none !important;
    color: #b4d333 !important;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    background-color: none;
    color: #b4d333 !important;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #fff;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:before {
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url("http://whatsahead.com/closuremediatest/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/arrow-down.png");
    background-position: 40% 40%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 11px;
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 8px;
    width: 18px;
}

#masthead.sticky #navigation .navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding: 17px 25px;
}`
```

Javacript scrollto:

```
    ;(function (define) {
    'use strict';
    define(['jquery'], function ($) {

        var $scrollTo = $.scrollTo = function( target, duration, settings ) {
            return $(window).scrollTo( target, duration, settings );
        };

        $scrollTo.defaults = {
            axis:'xy',
            duration: 0,
            limit:true
        };

        // Returns the element that needs to be animated to scroll the window.
        // Kept for backwards compatibility (specially for localScroll & serialScroll)
        $scrollTo.window = function( scope ) {
            return $(window)._scrollable();
        };

        // Hack, hack, hack :)
        // Returns the real elements to scroll (supports window/iframes, documents and regular nodes)
        $.fn._scrollable = function() {
            return this.map(function() {
                var elem = this,
                    isWin = !elem.nodeName || $.inArray( elem.nodeName.toLowerCase(),    
    ['iframe','#document','html','body'] ) != -1;

                    if (!isWin)
                        return elem;

                var doc = (elem.contentWindow || elem).document || elem.ownerDocument || elem;

                return /webkit/i.test(navigator.userAgent) || doc.compatMode == 'BackCompat' ?
                    doc.body :
                    doc.documentElement;
            });
        };

        $.fn.scrollTo = function( target, duration, settings ) {
            if (typeof duration == 'object') {
                settings = duration;
                duration = 0;
            }
            if (typeof settings == 'function')
                settings = { onAfter:settings };

            if (target == 'max')
                target = 9e9;

            settings = $.extend( {}, $scrollTo.defaults, settings );
            // Speed is still recognized for backwards compatibility
            duration = duration || settings.duration;
            // Make sure the settings are given right
            settings.queue = settings.queue && settings.axis.length > 1;

            if (settings.queue)
                // Let's keep the overall duration
                duration /= 2;
            settings.offset = both( settings.offset );
            settings.over = both( settings.over );

            return this._scrollable().each(function() {
                // Null target yields nothing, just like jQuery does
                if (target == null) return;

                var elem = this,
                    $elem = $(elem),
                    targ = target, toff, attr = {},
                    win = $elem.is('html,body');

                switch (typeof targ) {
                    // A number will pass the regex
                    case 'number':
                    case 'string':
                        if (/^([+-]=?)?\d+(\.\d+)?(px|%)?$/.test(targ)) {
                            targ = both( targ );
                            // We are done
                            break;
                        }
                        // Relative/Absolute selector, no break!
                        targ = win ? $(targ) : $(targ, this);
                        if (!targ.length) return;
                    case 'object':
                        // DOMElement / jQuery
                        if (targ.is || targ.style)
                            // Get the real position of the target
                            toff = (targ = $(targ)).offset();
                }

                var offset = $.isFunction(settings.offset) && settings.offset(elem, targ) || 
    settings.offset;

                $.each( settings.axis.split(''), function( i, axis ) {
                    var Pos = axis == 'x' ? 'Left' : 'Top',
                        pos = Pos.toLowerCase(),
                        key = 'scroll' + Pos,
                        old = elem[key],
                        max = $scrollTo.max(elem, axis);

                    if (toff) {// jQuery / DOMElement
                        attr[key] = toff[pos] + ( win ? 0 : old - $elem.offset()[pos] );

                        // If it's a dom element, reduce the margin
                        if (settings.margin) {
                            attr[key] -= parseInt(targ.css('margin'+Pos)) || 0;
                            attr[key] -= parseInt(targ.css('border'+Pos+'Width')) || 0;
                        }

                        attr[key] += offset[pos] || 0;

                        if(settings.over[pos])
                            // Scroll to a fraction of its width/height
                            attr[key] += targ[axis=='x'?'width':'height']() * settings.over[pos];
                    } else {
                        var val = targ[pos];
                        // Handle percentage values
                        attr[key] = val.slice && val.slice(-1) == '%' ?
                            parseFloat(val) / 100 * max
                            : val;
                    }

                    // Number or 'number'
                    if (settings.limit && /^\d+$/.test(attr[key]))
                        // Check the limits
                        attr[key] = attr[key] <= 0 ? 0 : Math.min( attr[key], max );

                    // Queueing axes
                    if (!i && settings.queue) {
                        // Don't waste time animating, if there's no need.
                        if (old != attr[key])
                            // Intermediate animation
                            animate( settings.onAfterFirst );
                        // Don't animate this axis again in the next iteration.
                        delete attr[key];
                    }
                });

                animate( settings.onAfter );

                function animate( callback ) {
                    $elem.animate( attr, duration, settings.easing, callback && function() {
                        callback.call(this, targ, settings);
                    });
                }
            }).end();
        };

        // Max scrolling position, works on quirks mode
        // It only fails (not too badly) on IE, quirks mode.
        $scrollTo.max = function( elem, axis ) {
            var Dim = axis == 'x' ? 'Width' : 'Height',
                scroll = 'scroll'+Dim;

            if (!$(elem).is('html,body'))
                return elem[scroll] - $(elem)[Dim.toLowerCase()]();

            var size = 'client' + Dim,
                html = elem.ownerDocument.documentElement,
                body = elem.ownerDocument.body;

            return Math.max( html[scroll], body[scroll] ) - Math.min( html[size]  , body[size]   );
        };

        function both( val ) {
            return $.isFunction(val) || $.isPlainObject(val) ? val : { top:val, left:val };
        }

        // AMD requirement
        return $scrollTo;
    })
    }(typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define : function (deps, factory) {
    if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) {
        // Node
        module.exports = factory(require('jquery'));
    } else {
        factory(jQuery);
    }
    }));
```

Javascript smoothscroll:

```
 function ssc_init() {
  if (!document.body) return;
  var e = document.body;
  var t = document.documentElement;
  var n = window.innerHeight;
  var r = e.scrollHeight;
  ssc_root = document.compatMode.indexOf("CSS") >= 0 ? t : e;
  ssc_activeElement = e;
  ssc_initdone = true;
  if (top != self) {
    ssc_frame = true
  } else if (r > n && (e.offsetHeight <= n || t.offsetHeight <= n)) {
    ssc_root.style.height = "auto";
    if (ssc_root.offsetHeight <= n) {
      var i = document.createElement("div");
      i.style.clear = "both";
      e.appendChild(i)
    }
  }
  if (!ssc_fixedback) {
    e.style.backgroundAttachment = "scroll";
    t.style.backgroundAttachment = "scroll"
  }
  if (ssc_keyboardsupport) {
    ssc_addEvent("keydown", ssc_keydown)
  }
}

function ssc_scrollArray(e, t, n, r) {
  r || (r = 1e3);
  ssc_directionCheck(t, n);
  ssc_que.push({
    x: t,
    y: n,
    lastX: t < 0 ? .99 : -.99,
    lastY: n < 0 ? .99 : -.99,
    start: +(new Date)
  });
  if (ssc_pending) {
    return
  }
  var i = function() {
    var s = +(new Date);
    var o = 0;
    var u = 0;
    for (var a = 0; a < ssc_que.length; a++) {
      var f = ssc_que[a];
      var l = s - f.start;
      var c = l >= ssc_animtime;
      var h = c ? 1 : l / ssc_animtime;
      if (ssc_pulseAlgorithm) {
        h = ssc_pulse(h)
      }
      var p = f.x * h - f.lastX >> 0;
      var d = f.y * h - f.lastY >> 0;
      o += p;
      u += d;
      f.lastX += p;
      f.lastY += d;
      if (c) {
        ssc_que.splice(a, 1);
        a--
      }
    }
    if (t) {
      var v = e.scrollLeft;
      e.scrollLeft += o;
      if (o && e.scrollLeft === v) {
        t = 0
      }
    }
    if (n) {
      var m = e.scrollTop;
      e.scrollTop += u;
      if (u && e.scrollTop === m) {
        n = 0
      }
    }
    if (!t && !n) {
      ssc_que = []
    }
    if (ssc_que.length) {
      setTimeout(i, r / ssc_framerate + 1)
    } else {
      ssc_pending = false
    }
  };
  setTimeout(i, 0);
  ssc_pending = true
}

function ssc_wheel(e) {
  if (!ssc_initdone) {
    ssc_init()
  }
  var t = e.target;
  var n = ssc_overflowingAncestor(t);
  if (!n || e.defaultPrevented || ssc_isNodeName(ssc_activeElement, "embed") || ssc_isNodeName(t, "embed") && /\.pdf/i.test(t.src)) {
    return true
  }
  var r = e.wheelDeltaX || 0;
  var i = e.wheelDeltaY || 0;
  if (!r && !i) {
    i = e.wheelDelta || 0
  }
  if (Math.abs(r) > 1.2) {
    r *= ssc_stepsize / 120
  }
  if (Math.abs(i) > 1.2) {
    i *= ssc_stepsize / 120
  }
  ssc_scrollArray(n, -r, -i);
  e.preventDefault()
}

function ssc_keydown(e) {
  var t = e.target;
  var n = e.ctrlKey || e.altKey || e.metaKey;
  if (/input|textarea|embed/i.test(t.nodeName) || t.isContentEditable || e.defaultPrevented || n) {
    return true
  }
  if (ssc_isNodeName(t, "button") && e.keyCode === ssc_key.spacebar) {
    return true
  }
  var r, i = 0,
      s = 0;
  var o = ssc_overflowingAncestor(ssc_activeElement);
  var u = o.clientHeight;
  if (o == document.body) {
    u = window.innerHeight
  }
  switch (e.keyCode) {
  case ssc_key.up:
    s = -ssc_arrowscroll;
    break;
  case ssc_key.down:
    s = ssc_arrowscroll;
    break;
  case ssc_key.spacebar:
    r = e.shiftKey ? 1 : -1;
    s = -r * u * .9;
    break;
  case ssc_key.pageup:
    s = -u * .9;
    break;
  case ssc_key.pagedown:
    s = u * .9;
    break;
  case ssc_key.home:
    s = -o.scrollTop;
    break;
  case ssc_key.end:
    var a = o.scrollHeight - o.scrollTop - u;
    s = a > 0 ? a + 10 : 0;
    break;
  case ssc_key.left:
    i = -ssc_arrowscroll;
    break;
  case ssc_key.right:
    i = ssc_arrowscroll;
    break;
  default:
    return true
  }
  ssc_scrollArray(o, i, s);
  e.preventDefault()
}

function ssc_mousedown(e) {
  ssc_activeElement = e.target
}

function ssc_setCache(e, t) {
  for (var n = e.length; n--;) ssc_cache[ssc_uniqueID(e[n])] = t;
  return t
}

function ssc_overflowingAncestor(e) {
  var t = [];
  var n = ssc_root.scrollHeight;
  do {
    var r = ssc_cache[ssc_uniqueID(e)];
    if (r) {
      return ssc_setCache(t, r)
    }
    t.push(e);
    if (n === e.scrollHeight) {
      if (!ssc_frame || ssc_root.clientHeight + 10 < n) {
        return ssc_setCache(t, document.body)
      }
    } else if (e.clientHeight + 10 < e.scrollHeight) {
      overflow = getComputedStyle(e, "").getPropertyValue("overflow");
      if (overflow === "scroll" || overflow === "auto") {
        return ssc_setCache(t, e)
      }
    }
  } while (e = e.parentNode)
}

function ssc_addEvent(e, t, n) {
  window.addEventListener(e, t, n || false)
}

function ssc_removeEvent(e, t, n) {
  window.removeEventListener(e, t, n || false)
}

function ssc_isNodeName(e, t) {
  return e.nodeName.toLowerCase() === t.toLowerCase()
}

function ssc_directionCheck(e, t) {
  e = e > 0 ? 1 : -1;
  t = t > 0 ? 1 : -1;
  if (ssc_direction.x !== e || ssc_direction.y !== t) {
    ssc_direction.x = e;
    ssc_direction.y = t;
    ssc_que = []
  }
}

function ssc_pulse_(e) {
  var t, n, r;
  e = e * ssc_pulseScale;
  if (e < 1) {
    t = e - (1 - Math.exp(-e))
  } else {
    n = Math.exp(-1);
    e -= 1;
    r = 1 - Math.exp(-e);
    t = n + r * (1 - n)
  }
  return t * ssc_pulseNormalize
}

function ssc_pulse(e) {
  if (e >= 1) return 1;
  if (e <= 0) return 0;
  if (ssc_pulseNormalize == 1) {
    ssc_pulseNormalize /= ssc_pulse_(1)
  }
  return ssc_pulse_(e)
}

var ssc_framerate = 150;
var ssc_animtime = 500;
var ssc_stepsize = 150;
var ssc_pulseAlgorithm = true;
var ssc_pulseScale = 6;
var ssc_pulseNormalize = 1;
var ssc_keyboardsupport = true;
var ssc_arrowscroll = 50;
var ssc_frame = false;
var ssc_direction = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
};

var ssc_initdone = false;
var ssc_fixedback = true;
var ssc_root = document.documentElement;
var ssc_activeElement;
var ssc_key = {
  left: 37,
  up: 38,
  right: 39,
  down: 40,
  spacebar: 32,
  pageup: 33,
  pagedown: 34,
  end: 35,
  home: 36
};

var ssc_que = [];
var ssc_pending = false;
var ssc_cache = {};

setInterval(function() {
  ssc_cache = {}
}, 10 * 1e3);

var ssc_uniqueID = function() {
  var e = 0;
  return function(t) {
    return t.ssc_uniqueID || (t.ssc_uniqueID = e++)
  }
}();

var ischrome = /chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());

if (ischrome) {
  ssc_addEvent("mousedown", ssc_mousedown);
  ssc_addEvent("mousewheel", ssc_wheel);
  ssc_addEvent("load", ssc_init)
}
```

Comment: Please update your post to include any/all of the related code causing the issue so that the members of the site can assist.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a Javascript problem but a CSS issue.

First of all you logo img is too big. it's pushing the navbar down and mismatching the calculation. Let's fix it:

```
.navbar-brand img {
    max-height: 110px;
}
```

Then  we must add a margin to the top of the page content.

```
.title-area, .page-content {
    margin-top: 40px;
}
```

Add it in your custom.csss and it will solve your problem

Comment: I wasn't able to use that exact css as they did not all exist but did something similar and it is still not correct. Especially when on the top for the first time. Once I click on a link and then go to another it is close. I probably could play around with margins and padding to get it close. But still not right. I understand that because I increased the size of my navbar it is throwing everything off, but can I change "the calculation" to be able to bring it back together?

Comment: I wrote this css classes in your page by using google chrome controle. I guess if you just add that lines in your style.css it may work

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by editing javascript file. It was removing the "sticky" class when scrolled to the far top which voided some of my css edits I wanted to stay with. Therefore, by editing the javascript so that the document was always "sticky" I was able to make the header larger as I desired.